# Is it possible to make the sub-directory of 'gh-pages' accessible via link?

Tags: github, git-branch, subdirectory

Consider the following example:

```
username = case
```

So to access user's page (index.html), one would need to enter:

```
http://case.github.io (branch: master)
```

Now suppose there is another repository created within the above one with the name "Data", e.g. after publishing it, its index.html can be accessed as follows:

```
http://case.github.io/Data (branch: gh-pages)
```

Basically, what I want to know is that, if it is possible to access repository's ("Evidence01") index.html via:

```
http://case.github.io/Data/Evidence01 (branch: ?)
```

and how to achieve it?

Thanks and my apologies if the above sounded confusing.

Comment: In your example, do you intend for "Evidence01" to be a subdirectory of "Data", or are you trying to have "Evidence01" be its own repository?

Comment: I attempted to make the third repository at the same time pushing it as a sub-directory of the Data repository, just as it was done with "Data" and "case" repositories. 

Yet it would end up in error for me. I couldn't keep up with the results of my attempts, hence I felt to ask online for help or clarification.

I only wish to achieve the effect from entering something like "http://case.github.io/Data/Evidence01" in the browser and get to a web page. It doesn't matter much if it is a new repository or sub-directory, as long as it works the way I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a repository called `Data` with a subdirectory called `Evidence01` containing an `index.html` and assuming it is setup correctly as GitHub (Project) Pages you should be get the desired result based on the additional information you provided in your comment.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Although I had to ignore the fact of an error when I tried to push the "commit changes" on the user's repository. It made me think if it could not process it, there would be no desired result achieved anyways. Well, as long as the desired result is achieved, I can ignore it for now.